# Lein Deployment on Clojars and Dependencies

Tags: hadoop, clojure, hbase, leiningen, clojars

I am working on an application that uses Apache Hbase as its datastore.  I coded up a clojure wrapper around some common hbase operations,

https://github.com/mobiusinversion/hbase

and pushed it to clojars.

https://clojars.org/hbase

In my hbase wrapper I import the Bytes class:

```
(ns hbase.table
    (:gen-class)
    (:refer-clojure :exclude [get])
    (:import [clojure.lang PersistentVector PersistentArrayMap]
             [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util Bytes]
             [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client Put Get HTable Scan]))
```

Then in another project called "wtf" I declare the wrapper as a dependency, and this works well, it simply pulls the jar down from clojars.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:wtf $ lein do clean, deps
... blah blah
Retrieving org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar from central
Retrieving ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.jar from central
Retrieving commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.jar from central
Retrieving net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.6.1/jets3t-0.6.1.jar from central
Retrieving hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar from central
Retrieving oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar from central
Retrieving org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.1.1/core-3.1.1.jar from central
Retrieving org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.8.8/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar from central
Retrieving hbase/hbase/0.1.1/hbase-0.1.1.jar from clojars
MacBook-Pro-2:wtf $
```

However the Bytes class (and all the other Hadoop classes) cannot be found in the new project:

```
$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 58693
REPL-y 0.1.10
Clojure 1.5.1
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
Commands: (user/help)
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
          (user/sourcery function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
Examples from clojuredocs.org: [clojuredocs or cdoc]
          (user/clojuredocs name-here)
          (user/clojuredocs "ns-here" "name-here")

user=> (use 'hbase.schema)
ClassNotFoundException org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:202)

user=> (use 'hbase.config)
ClassNotFoundException org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:202)

user=> (use 'hbase.table)
ClassNotFoundException org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:202)

user=>
```

I have no idea why the hadoop classes are not either being pulled in as dependencies by Leiningen, or packaged as part of my clojars deployment.  How can I get these classes to be visible???

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is related to the order in which dependencies are declared with qualifiers:

This did not register the HBase dependency

```
(defproject hbase "0.1.0"
:description "HBase Access in Clojure"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License" :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:url "https://github.com/mobiusinversion/hbase"
:dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
        [org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core "1.2.0"]
    [org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-test "1.2.0" :scope "test"]
    [org.apache.hbase/hbase "0.94.6.1" :classifier "tests" :scope "test"]
    [org.apache.hbase/hbase "0.94.6.1"]]
:plugins [[lein-marginalia "0.7.1"]])
```

This however does:

```
(defproject hbase "0.1.3"
:description "HBase Access in Clojure"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License" :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:url "https://github.com/mobiusinversion/hbase"
:dependencies [
    [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
    [org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core "1.2.0"]
    [org.apache.hbase/hbase "0.94.6.1"]
    [org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-test "1.2.0"]
    [org.apache.hbase/hbase "0.94.6.1" :classifier "tests" :scope "test"]]
:plugins [[lein-marginalia "0.7.1"]])
```